# Threads with no end in Java

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I have a program written in Java which uses 3 threads. Everything is working fine in the IDE (Netbeans) and when I kill it it destroys all the threads. When I launch it from the command line and Ctrl-C it the threads keep running. What's the best way to deal with this ?

Does it kill the main thread as I guess I can use flags after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You can have `some loop control mechanism` for your threads using boolean.

**2.** Else try using `Daemon threads`, So as there will be **No Non-Daemon thread, the JVM will get closed.**

**By defalut its Non-Daemon**, but you can **set the thread as Daemon before you call** `start()` method **on** the **thread of execution**...

`The JVM will terminate ONLY when all the non-daemon threads including the Main thread has` `terminated.`

**Eg:**

```
      Thread t = new Thread(MyClass);
      t.setDaemon(true);
```

Comment: (new Thread(new SerialReader(data, in, "ioReader"))).start();
(new Thread(new SerialWriter(out, "ioWriter"))).start();
(new Thread(new TickTock(data,"timeWatch"))).start();                                
(new Thread(new testclass(data,"tester"))).start(); 
(new Thread(new testtimer(data,"ticktick"))).start();

Comment: (new Thread(new SerialReader(data, in, "ioReader"))).start();
(new Thread(new SerialWriter(out, "ioWriter"))).start();
(new Thread(new TickTock(data,"timeWatch"))).start();                                
(new Thread(new testclass(data,"tester"))).start(); 
(new Thread(new testtimer(data,"ticktick"))).start();

How Would you add setDameon(true) in the above scenario. Am i correct in thinking that if setDaemon is true that if the parent thread is killed any child threads will then die with it ?

Comment: I said create all the threads as Daemon threads, they work the same, but Unlike the Non-daemon threads, they wont restrict the jvm to terminate, even if they are running.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a shutdown hook on your main thread to clean up the other threads gracefully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("System shutting down");
      // tell your other threads to shut down from here
      // the best way to do this is to set a flag 
      // that they will pick up on and exit gracefully
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On most Linux systems that I know about, pressing control-c if the program is in the foreground causes a interrupt signal (SIGINT) sent to the JVM which kills all of the threads (daemon or not) and exits.  I tried this [stupid little program](http://pastebin.com/ardG9QRN) on Mac OSX and CentOS Linux and it exits fine with control-c.

One thing that has not been mentioned here is that signal handlers may be trapping the interrupt signal.  They allow you to catch control-c (and other signals) so you can do something intelligent with them.  They are very OS dependent (of course) and if you catch the interrupt signal (SIGINT is usually sent by control-c) and *don't* stop the JVM, you are going to have problems.

But in any case, you can do something like the following:

```
...
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
// catch the control-c signal, "TERM" is another common kill signal
Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), handler);
...

private static class MyHandler implements SignalHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Signal arg0) {
        // interrupt your threads
        // clean up stuff
        // set shutdown flags
        // ...
    }
}
```

Again, I would say that it is a bad practice to catch interrupt signal (control-c) and *not* take  the JVM down.  This might be the problem with your application.

Comment: Hi Grey thanks for this comment. I have some additional question. If there were no threads just the main class as it were with while true loop. No signal Handlers nothing ... and you Ctrl-C it what happens within the application ? Does it still quit ?

Comment: Can you add this answer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755512/threads-java-inturrupts/11761627#11761627

Comment: I've added to that question @DevilCode.  I was trying to separate my answers however.

Comment: The behavior with control-c is OS dependent.  Without a signal handler, control-c should bring the JVM down I believe under most Unix variants (including Mac OSX).  Is that not working for you @DevilCode?

Comment: If it's just a simple main program with a loop its working fine, but if its got threads off of it everything stays running after Ctrl-C. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Huh.  When I control-c my program, it stops immediately.  I'm on centos (Linux ... 2.6.18-8.el5 #1 SMP Thu Mar 15 19:46:53 EDT 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).  Here's my stupid code: http://pastebin.com/ardG9QRN

Comment: I concur it halts also on my attempt using the same code. I will test again my original code that caused the issue and get right back to you.

Comment: Ok Embarrassingly Ctrl-C is now killing it every time. I wonder if I made a boo boo at some silly hour in the morning with my ps aux | grep argument.  I don't know.

Either way its killing it all now. However, I have learned a lot so far and think  will write up a summery (& sample program) on how to kill threads gracefully even with Ctrl-c.

Grey would you be ok to look it over. I will keen an eye on my program in the mean time in case its an intermittent thing. This has been a great discussion and will keep it open until the summery post.

Comment: I'd be curious @DevilCode, what else you have to learn that is not in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755512/threads-java-inturrupts/11761627#11761627

Answer (score 0):

> Does it kill the main thread as I guess I can use flags after that?

I don't know what Ctrl-C in particular does, but if you make your "permanent" threads daemon threads, your app should terminate when all the non-daemon threads have terminated. See the [`Thread` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for more details.

Comment: Under Unixen, control-c sends a SIGINT to the JVM which kills it unless you have a signal handler defined.  This may be under Windows too.  As @Ben mentions, it will call the shutdown hooks on the way down.  This is even if you have non-daemon threads running.

Comment: @Gray: Yes, that's what I'd normally have expected. It's unclear why that's not happening in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You have one thread as a master thread and the others as daemon threads.

Use Thread.setDaemon(true)

Answer (score 0):

Java executable is made to respond to ctrl-c on Windows (ctrl-\ on unix) by producing a thread dump to stdout. You can still kill it by ctrl-break on Windows.

Comment: Do you have an example ? does it throw some excepton that I can catch?

Comment: Under Unix @Marko, it is SIGQUIT that generates a thread dump -- not SIGINT.