# How to create a delay without try/catch?

Tags: java, delay

Is there a way to create a delay without having to use try/catch?

I tried using the `Thread.sleep(5000);`and `wait(5);` commands but it keeps throwing a `InterruptedException` error unless I use try/catch. I want to be able to use simple commands because of how much I use the commands.

Comment: `.sleep(timeInMs)`

Comment: In short, no. Because (if for no other reason) the user might end the program immediately. What should happen then?

Comment: Just add the _throws_ declaration to your method declaration.  This will remove the requirement to have _Thread.sleep_ within a _try-catch_.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That comment is very misleading. `InterruptedException` __cannot__ be triggered by the user directly, e.g. CTRL+C or 'nice' killing the app (posix `kill pid`) _does not_ cause InterruptedExceptions. It just hard-kills all threads, but your shutdownhooks will run, and any files registered for deletion on VM termination do get deleted. The ONLY way threads get interrupted if you or some other code you choose to run (given that the JVM doesn't just do this on its own volition) calls `oneOfYourThreads.interrupt()`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot [Sauce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761627/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that 'sauce' confirms what I said and confirms your comment is misleading. I'd say "Sauce" is.. just piling on with the misleading commentary.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't throw an interrupted exception - it potentially can so at runtime. So you need to wrap it.

You can create a function that has the try catch and call that instead of writing try catch each time like

```
void dontCareSleep(long time) {
try { Thread.sleep(time) } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Now you can use this method everywhere

Another option is to use kotlin instead where the sleep doesn't need to be try caught everytime

Comment: Please at least specifiy the exact exception you want to catch, otherwise you also swallow completely unrelated stuff that might actually be bugs. Since this is the top answer, it would be cool if you correct it before someone copy pastas this. Also, prefer using `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)` and similar. Or at least write the unit to the parameter, `timeMillis`.

Comment: Also, you should almost definitely re-set the interrupted flag on the thread, rather than just swallowing the exception without taking any action.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a method or lambda. You can put it in your library.

```
public static void sleep(long mill){
  try {
     Thread.sleep(mill);
  } catch(InterruptedException e){
       Thread.currentThread()
             .interrupt();
  }
}
```

Or create a lambda.  Here a `LongConsumer` is used.

```
LongConsumer sleep = (delay) -> {
     try {
         Thread.sleep(delay);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        Thread.currentThread()
              .interrupt(); 
 };
```

And invoke it as follows:

```
sleep.accept(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you want to do a certain task many times, you write a method, instead of copy/pasting the same code over and over. "Just sleep for a little bit" sounds like a very simple job but it really isn't, so, into a method it goes!

```
/**
 * Pauses this thread for {@code millis} milliseconds.
 *
 * If interrupted, the thread restarts immediately, and the
 * interruption flag remains set.
 */
public static void sleep(long millis) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(millis);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Best course of action is to stop sleeping but propagate
    // the interruption so the caller gets to deal with it.
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:

#### 1) Coroutines

Try using `coroutines` to work with. It's easy and will not block your main thread

Call function

```
addDelay(500) {
    // showToast
}
```

Declare function

```
fun addDelay(timeMillis: Int = 1000, callback: () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        delay(timeMillis.toLong())
        callback.invoke()
    }
}
```

#### 2) Handler

Call function

```
withDelay(500) {
    // showToast
}
```

Declare function

```
fun withDelay(timeMillis: Int = 1000, callback: () -> Unit) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(block, timeMillis)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a even better option without using Thread.sleep() (which creates flakiness especially in tests) --> use Awaitility library, specially created to handle asynchronous calls.

here is an example for what are you trying to accomplish:

```
await().pollDelay(1000, MILLISECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> Assert.assertTrue(true));
```

It will check the assert (which is always true) after a delay of 1s.

You can create a method for it if you need to do it multiple times with different delay values:

```
    public void sleep( int delayValue) {

        await().pollDelay(delayValue, MILLISECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> Assert.assertTrue(true));
}
```

This library offers solutions also for other scenarios, for example if you want to wait for method to be executed first you can do:

```
@Test
public void updatesCustomerStatus() {
    // Publish an asynchronous message to a broker (e.g. RabbitMQ):
    messageBroker.publishMessage(updateCustomerStatusMessage);

    // Awaitility lets you wait until the asynchronous operation completes:
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(customerStatusIsUpdated());
    
}
```

See more usage scenarios on their website.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on why exactly you are sleeping, there might be better alternatives than Thread.sleep().

In case you are waiting for some asynchronous operation to complete in a test, I found tools like awaitility to be a nice choice, especially for testing.

Basically, instead of

```
longRunningOperation();

Thread.sleep();
assertTrue(getResult());
```

You would have

```
await()
  .atMost(Duration.ofMillis(x))
  .pollInterval(Duration.ofMillis(y))
  .until(getResult());
```

If the time is up, it'll throw an exception, but it's a RuntimeException, so you don't have to catch it.

I recently wrote an article about this topic if you are interested in more: https://link.medium.com/pJGQaQLnjAb